# How to convert this string to NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

Here is the string. Not sure what all the decimal precision is about.

```
"2015-02-28T21:56:40.5810156+00:00"
```

Comment: Duplicate is going the other way, but it's the same answer.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I was asking for a specific format. I have it now, but I'm not going to answer in a comment. Re-open so that other people can avoid playing around with the format string.

Comment: A specific string is pretty much by definition too localised.

Comment: Suit yourself. It's not like this question is going to disappear from the site. Better to have an answer than nothing IMO.

Comment: By the way, the suggested duplicate misses a key point in this RFC 3339/ISO 8601 date format, namely the need to specify a locale. See [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).